# Intersection types with Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, intersection

I have two union **types**:

```
type TypeA = string | number;
type TypeB = string | boolean;
```

I create an intersection **type** using the above:

```
type Combined = TypeA & TypeB;
```

Naturally, the `Combined` type will only be of type `string`, since it's the only type that intersects between **`TypeA`** and **`TypeB`**.

But if I change the *union* of **`TypeB`** and add a **Date** type, I get an unexpected behavior, e.g.:

```
type TypeA = string | number;
type TypeB = string | boolean | Date;
```

Create a new intersection type:

```
type Combined = TypeA & TypeB;
```

If I check the signature of the type, it looks like this:

```
type Combined = string | (string & Date) | (number & Date);
```

My question is why is this happening? Is this expected? I thought it would be of type **string** as it is the only **type** that ***intersects***.

Comment: This may be a bug in TypeScript, but `string & number` is `never`, and `string & Date` is `string & Date`, but I don't see what value you could assign to `string & Date`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Is it a bug? It seems to me (strange as it may be) that actually the intersection is not empty. For example, consider the result of the expression `Object.assign(0, new Date())`...

Comment: @CRice not sure exactly, but that seems to just be 0. You also get that with `Object.assign(0, '')`

Comment: Yes I think it is just `0`. The `Object.assign` is just tricking the type system as it's signature is set up to return the intersection of its argument's types. The actual value produced cannot be used as a `Date` object, as its type would suggest. I'm still not totally convinced the result should be `never` though, I think I could get a value that was usable as both a number and a Date with some prototype manipulation.

Comment: I'm just saying that TypeScript regards the _type_ of `string & number` as `never`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdlC8UDOwBOBLGBzKAyWArgLYBGEqA3EA

Answer (score 23):

It's not a bug; it's there to allow a (not well-publicized) feature called *branded* or *tagged* primitives.

---

It's pretty much impossible to have a value `v` at runtime which is both a `string` (the primitive, where `typeof v === "string"`, not a `String` wrapper object) and a `Date`.  In some sense, the type `string & Date` really is the same as `never`, since you can think of a TypeScript type as the set of all appropriate JavaScript values.  If there are no `string & Date` values, and there are no `never` values, then those types are logically equivalent.

So it would be plausible if the compiler were to eagerly reduce an intersection like `string & Date` to `never`.  It already does this for intersections of incompatible unit types like `"a" & 0`, and intersections of incompatible primitive types like `string & number`, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#31838](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838).  So why doesn't this happen when we intersect object types with primitives?

---

The reason is to allow a feature called *branded primitives* which emulate [nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) for primitives in TypeScript (mentioned in [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)).

TypeScript mostly has only [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) and [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases); if two types have the same structure but different names, *they are the same type*.  If you give an existing type a new name via a type alias, *they are the same type*.  Often that's just what you want, but sometimes you'd like to come up with two types which, while identical at runtime, need to be distinguished in your code because you don't want a developer to accidentally mix them up.

For example (and this might be a silly example):

```
type Username = string;
type Password = string;
declare function login(username: Username; password: Password): void;
```

Here we would like to make sure that someone who writes TypeScript code that calls `login` does not accidentally put the password in for the username or vice versa.  It would be nice if the above type aliases actually prevented you from doing this:

```
declare function getUsername(): Username;
declare function getPassword(): Password;
login(getPassword(), getUsername()); // no error, OOPS
```

but it doesn't.  The `Username` and `Password` types are both just `string`.  The fact that we are using different *names* doesn't change that.  So sometimes TypeScript developers would like their types to be nominal, to catch errors like the above.

There's a very long discussion in [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) about how to get nominal typing.  One way to do it for primitive types is with "branding", where you add a "phantom" distinguishing property that exists only in the type system *and not at runtime*.  So you could change the above to:

```
type Username = string & { __brand: "Username" };
type Password = string & { __brand: "Password" };
```

and suddenly you'd get the desired error here:

```
login(getPassword(), getUsername()); // error! Password not assignable to Username
```

Of course actually convincing the compiler that a particular `string` really is a `Username` or a `Password` consists of *lying* via something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function toUsername(x: string): Username {
    return x as Username; // <-- lying
}
```

---

But of course we know that at runtime you can't *really* have a value of type `Username` or `Password`, since if you take a primitive `string` it won't have a `__brand` property.  If the compiler decided to eagerly reduce these impossible-at-runtime branded types to `never`, they would break completely.  It would be even worse than just using the primitives, since nothing would be assignable to them, but they'd still be indistinguishable and allow mixups:

```
login(getPassword(), getUsername()); // no error again
```

And while this feature might not be very savory, it's being used in existing real-world TypeScript code, including the [TypeScript source code for the TypeScript compiler itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e044b56d7f61a1b769e13744b814464c832c5a47/src/compiler/types.ts#L4).  Reducing branded primitives to `never` would break too many people for it to be worth it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgOwIYFtoF4p2IgS2QHMoAyKAbygH0aAjRVZAEwC4oAieJNTTqAF8A3AFgAUKEhQACqjhwA7gHtELKDjyES5KrQZNWHTnIUq1AkRJYQAxgBtUiaADMArslvACy5FHvKxEQAFG4IKBgQHDwRmAA0uPhExBwAykkkAJQcAG7KBCxi4lAS1naOzlDunt6+UMQQwDF8EMHZsOEtRTYOTq4eXj5+DcCmSqosbRxj5oUSAUHIwSMzE20JI82RbZnCUAD0+1BIiKoAhLLy42pQyMrAUFcExGj09tDAyh28kaXi1YM6p8tphggAPDhaZLtEHQSgSKCIqDOYBuFBQMGPODfWIQIqCP62Xx4KDKZRgbE4ACMACYAMxYnFdA5HE6qP4tOBgVC2aAAeXJ2PhxSRUmgsI0twgOSQCNF4GgqxuOGQ0tlIsRPQq-RqQ38gRCYR+mGinUiCShJDSGWI7TyBSKcs15T6VQGtWGjVhUyZkSKSKgWtdAI99UaSsm7Qj-qRCxCKyus3WYaaZtBmV2LNuXzZiEexFQRD+AZDeuBadaEMS2ltpuNcKdAeRjTRfkx8l9mBjiIJ4kbROQJLJFMltIZHdh+KAA)

Comment: @jpaugh Please note that [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64614872/2) wasn't accurate.  A [unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) is inhabited by exactly one value.  So string literal types like `"a"` and numeric literal types like `0` are unit types (as well as `undefined` and `null`).  The types `string` and `number` are not unit types, as both `"a"` and `"b"` are valid values of type `string`.   And `string` and `number` are [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Comment: I see. Thanks for taking the time to explain. I'll add a small edit that helps me understand it better.

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behavior, intersection of primitives are simplified to `never`, while intersections of primitives with object types are not simplified (to enable thigs such as branded primitive types). `Date` is not a primitive, it is an object type defined in lib.d.ts

Give this, and the fact that typescript normalizes unions and intersections by moving the intersection inside we get

```
type TypeA = string | number;
type TypeB = string | boolean;

type Combined = TypeA & TypeB;
 => (string | number) & (string | boolean)
 // Distributivity kicks in 
 => (string & string) | (string & boolean) | (number & string) | (number & boolean)
 //  intersection simplification
 => string | never | never | never 
 // never melts away in a union
 => string
```

While in the second case we get

```
type TypeA = string | number;
type TypeB = string | boolean | Date;

type Combined = TypeA & TypeB;
 => (string | number) & (string | boolean | Date)
 // Distributivity kicks in 
 => (string & string) | (string & boolean) | (string & Date) | (number & string) | (number & boolean) | (number & Date)
 //  intersection simplification, but nothing is done about Date and any primitive
 => string | never | (string & Date) never | never | (number & Date)
 // never melts away in a union
 => string
```

If you want to extract any type from `TypeA` that is present in `TypeB` you might be better off using the `Extract` conditional type

```
type TypeA = string | number;
type TypeB = string | boolean | Date;

type Combined = Extract<TypeA, TypeB>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oGdgCcCWA7A5lAD5S4CuAtgEYSYDcAUKJLPAEIrpZ6ElUD2-ADYQAhrmJQAIqOARGTeFADC-anggATTgFEAHllEBjYAB44kBABpWkNgD46UAPTOuOAlCA)

Answer (score 2):

That's because Date is not a primitive type. incompatible primitive types reduce to `never`.

```
type TypeA = string | number;
type TypeB = string | boolean;

type Combined = TypeA & TypeB;
// string | (string & number) | (string & boolean)
// => string | never | never
// => string
```

It is easier for a developer to debug without that reduction.
You can try with your own class and it will have the same behaviour.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBfAUJpBPADvHAfAILQC80yATgJYB2A5tAD7QMCuAtgEbw0A3DhLFCAIUrUk9Zm2i8A9opDwwDeQmTC8haAHkGIXAAV63OkjoA3IlVqMW7JSrUb2i3gCt4wFM7omRn9oTgYAE3gAM0Z4cOERPQBhRT5Y8KlYEnIAMjF4cR1RFLSGOLM6CytbGCoswlyDI1NzSxt4YSA)

I looked for a more detailed answer and found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53545038/14438744