# why typescript string & number show never?

Tags: typescript

I was studing Typescript, but I have some confusion.

```js
type t = number & string // never
type t1 = number & boolean // never
type t2 = number & string[] // number & string[]
```

Why does it look different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection types with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614085/intersection-types-with-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Typescipt the instersection `&` of two primitive types is always never because a variabe cannot be both string and a number, but the intersection of two array/object is called as `branded object`
and one array/object with a primitive is a valid type and is called as `branded primitve` , so where do we use branded primitive ?
,
refer the below example

```
type SomeUrl = string & {'this is a url': {}};

let x = <SomeUrl>'';
```